# How much does the difficulty change based on game 1

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

I have just started playing the game and realized that it would be a very different game depending on which virus gets the sticker in the first game.  I am wondering if my think is correct and which color would be the easiest verse the hardest?

February spoilers:

> I am talking about the virus which becomes incurable in February of the game

Comment: We won the first 4 games in a row, struggling in the first 2, getting sort of easy wins on#3 and #4, and then got decimated in#5. So luck plays a role and how well you predict the best combination of roles for the game.

Comment: We ended up with a board that wasn't fun the play in December since with the setup we had we had a very low chance of winning because of the objectives and decided not to play the last round.  We enjoyed the experience but the game definitely kicked our ass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some difference in difficulty based on which color becomes faded; but shouldn't change things very much compared to other random chance elements in the game.

As a whole, Blue being faded makes for the most difficult games.

The biggest difference between the colors is that they each have a different number of connections to other colors. This increases the number of faded counters that will end up on other colors on average.

Based on this statistic, blue is a difficult color to get, because it has 13 total connections to other colors, compared to 9 for Black, 8 for Yellow, and 6 for Red.

There are some other factors such as the number of internal connections; but ultimately which random cards you draw and when both from the player card deck and the infection deck will have a bigger luck-based impact on how difficult it is compared to which of the 4 colors ends up faded.

For more details and analysis, [see here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2061649/what-color-worst-full-game-spoilers) (where I got my numbers from).